# Python 2 Notebook in JuliaBox and Plotting Graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, julia

I am using a Python 2 notebook in JuliaBox.  I am attempting to plot some data, but I keep getting the error:

```
TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Julia itself has the capabilities to plot via python in a Julia notebook.  I've tested this myself.  The PyPlot command accesses the matplotlib.pyplot, right?

```
using PyPlot
plot([1,2,3,4])
```

However, the Python 2 notebook is causing me difficulty.  Here's what I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.plot([1,2,3])
```

Perhaps the notebook doesn't have the capability to plot?  Thanks!

Comment: It should be `using PyPlot`, i.e. do not capitalize the `U`.

Comment: Thanks.  That was a typo.  I have a lower-case u in my actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Julia doesn't ask you to do so explicitly, but when using matplotlib in python, you need to instruct it to *show* the resulting plot.

i.e. in python add the line:

```
plt.show()
```

I will also point out that the arguments you passed are lists, not numpy arrays. Your example will still work, but presumably (given you imported numpy) you meant to be working with arrays.

Comment: I have just tested python 2 on juliabox, you're right I got the same.  This just seems to be a bug on juliabox; they must have configured their server incorrectly, not taking into account graphical output in their ipython configuration. It would be worth contacting them / filing a bug.

Comment: Thanks for checking.  I didn't include the plt.show() line because I don't have issues with it.  While I wait for Juliabox to fix this bug, do you know another online python IDE (something similar to Juliabox)?

Comment: Does it have to be online? you can run python notebooks locally. Also, if what you're *really* after is a actually just a good IDE to write in, then I would highly recommend `spyder`. It has a matlab-like interface, and you get instant help on every function you type, as you type it.

Comment: But yes, I'm pretty sure you can upload interactive ipynb notebooks on github. E.g. [https://github.com/blog/1995-github-jupyter-notebooks-3](https://github.com/blog/1995-github-jupyter-notebooks-3)